# Edit Shopify Metafields/Product Options

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm using Shopify to run a sort of Kickstarter campaign on a custom product, whereby if the goal is reached the item will be made. I need to update the number of the items sold during the campaign, I'm storing the number sold as either a product option or metafield however right now i'd have to update these values manually every time one is sold.

My question is whether or not I am able to edit the value of a product variant option or metafield preferably using liquid - so that on completion of the order I can update the number of sold items.

Comment: Why don't you use the variant / stock control by shopify?

Comment: I cannot use the stock control unfortunately as it's managed by tradegecko. Is there actually a way of editing the variant options?

Comment: can you exactly point why do you want the same variants to be duplicated so you need to sync stock between them?

Comment: I don't want the variants to be duplicated, I want to be able to update a variant option as not to use value from TradeGecko as the items being sold are custom from a large batch but we also sell the same item without a custom logo on.

Comment: please be more specific or mail me directly and I'll try to help

Answer (score 1):

*In Shopify*, you cannot directly modify product variant options or metafields using Liquid code. Liquid is primarily used for rendering dynamic content on your store's frontend, and it does not have write access to modify data in your Shopify store.

`To update the number of items sold during your campaign automatically, you have a couple of options:`

1. Use Shopify's Admin API: You can use Shopify's Admin API in
   conjunction with a server-side script or app to update the product
   variant options or metafields when an order is completed. Your
   script or app can listen for the "order completed" event and then
   make API calls to update the desired product variant options or
   metafields accordingly.
2. Utilize existing Shopify apps: There are Shopify apps available in
   the Shopify App Store specifically designed for managing and
   tracking crowdfunding campaigns. Such apps can handle the automatic
   updates of product variant options or metafields based on the number
   of sold items in a Kickstarter-like scenario.

It would be best to explore the available apps in the Shopify App Store to find a solution that fits your needs. Look for apps that offer features for custom product campaigns, crowdfunding, or inventory management.

Remember to carefully read the app descriptions, features, and reviews to ensure they align with your requirements. Additionally, consider contacting the app developer directly to ask specific questions about their app's capabilities before installing or purchasing.

While Liquid alone may not have the capability to update product variant options or metafields, combining it with the appropriate API or app integration can help you achieve the desired functionality for your Kickstarter campaign on Shopify.